# when is it most appropriate to use a micro framework? (instead of something like rails, django or catalyst)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, frameworks, sinatra, catalyst

I have spent some time familiarizing myself with

rails (ruby),
django...and other things like zope and pylons/pyramid (python),
catalyst (perl)

but often find myself wanting to use 
sinatra (ruby)
bottle...or flask...(python)
dancer...(perl)

I'm not entirely sure...when I'm about to start a new project, which I should use. 
What should be the deciding factor that makes me switch from a micro framework to something more substantial. Is it just when I would otherwise have too much SQL to write? I think not, because if that were the case I could just use an ORM library/module.

My main issue is a fear of choosing something that other developers would not understand if someone else needed to fix the site at a later point in time. Still I am still not sure what should inform my opinion.

Comment: Your last point reminds me of [this essay by Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With miсro frameworks you have more freedom in the use of libraries, you can add what you think is right. In large frameworks such as Django and etc already much that is "screwed" and there are certain rules and best practices how best to write certain things.